# You see me every day

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My solem wish is to break free,
If you double up, I shall not flee.
To the ground I tie you with my yarn,
in prisons the keep me, so I don't harm.
Thick and thin and I come in various colours,
sometimes I'm unseen in the summers.
Children fear me for my riddle,
usually I lay in the middle.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> **SHOELACES**

My solem wish is to break free,

> They love coming undone

If you double up, I shall not flee.

> Tied properly, they don't

To the ground I tie you with my yarn,

> Shoelaces are often made of cotton/similar material, and are used to lace up footwear

in prisons the keep me, so I don't harm.

> Shoelaces are confiscated in prisons, to prevent prisoners hanging themselves

Thick and thin and I come in various colours,

> Kiddie shoes have colourful laces

sometimes I'm unseen in the summers.

> Because people eschew covered footwear for slippers

Children fear me for my riddle,

> How to tie shoelaces are a puzzle for children at first

usually I lay in the middle.

> Shoelaces are commonly oriented in the center of shoes

Comment: Nicley done! That's what I thought of.

Answer (score 2):

Could you possibly be a

> [image] (zipper)?

My solem wish is to break free,

> A zipper usually holds together pieces of cloth.

If you double up, I shall not flee.

> When both sides of the zip are connected, the zipper is *intended* to stay shut (even if I've had several zippers who didn't).

To the ground I tie you with my yarn,

> There is plastic on one side (the connecting one) and yarn on the other side with is sewn.

in prisons the keep me, so I don't harm.

> Zippers are usually protected by some fabric, or rather, protects the skin from the zipper.

Thick and thin and I come in various colours,

> Well, zippers do.

sometimes I'm unseen in the summers.

> Zippers are often put on jackets and other warm clothing.

Children fear me for my riddle,

> Well, this is a bit of the stretch, but children usually fear the toothy side, which sort of makes a riddle...

usually I lay in the middle.

> Zippers are usually put in the middle.

Comment: Not what I was thinking of, yet a nice answer I didn't expect ^^ What were your guesses for each line?

Comment: Done: But I don't know... some of the explanations are somewhat taken out of thin air :-)

Comment: Still, I enjoyed reading it +1 ^^